# How to CRUD Postgres Point data type using go pg

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I am using Point datatype for storing coordinates in Postgres DB. How do I map Point datatype to Go lang datatypes? I am not finding any documentation for the same.

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg doesn't provide support for the point type, at least not as far as I can tell... Try pgx's [pgtype.Point](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx/pgtype#Point) it implements the scanner and valuer interfaces and may be able to work together with go-pg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go-pg does not have native support to Point type (as of PostGIS). 
What I've done to overpass that (may not be the best solution but I did manage to make it work) was to put on my model individual Latitude and Longitude fields, and on the query itself use `ColumnExpr` to get individual values using `ST_X` (for longitude) and `ST_Y` (for latitude, don't forget that).

Model:

```
type MyModel struct {
    ID              int64
    Name            string
    LocationLat     float64
    LocationLon     float64
}
```

Query:

```
err := db.Model(&myModel).
        Column("id", "name").
        ColumnExpr("ST_X(location) AS location_lon").
        ColumnExpr("ST_Y(location) AS location_lat").
        Where("id = ?", id).
        Select()
```